# Prove this series involving Bessel function of first kind

Tags: sequences-and-series, bessel-functions

I came across this series when solving a time-dependent Poisson's equation using series expansion

$$
\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{1}{\alpha_k J_1(\alpha_k)}=\frac{1}{2}
$$
where $\alpha_k$ is the $k$-th root of $J_0(x)$. I can confirm this numerically, but I want to prove this. Any help is appreciated. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Integrate $g(z)=\frac{1}{2 \pi i z J_0(z)}$ over a large rectangle with zero as the origin.
You might use the fact that $J_0(z)\sim e^{\mp iz}/\sqrt{z}$ as $\Im(z)\rightarrow\pm\infty$ to show that the contributions of the contour vanish in the limit of an infinite rectangle.
This means that the the sum of all residues is just $0$.
$$
\oint g(z)=0=\text{res}(g(z=0))+2\sum_{k=1}\text{res}(g(z=\alpha_k))
$$
Note that the factor 2 above is due to the symmetry of Bessel zeros $J_0(x)=0\rightarrow J_0(-x)=0$ and that all poles are simple.

The calculation of the resiudes is easy if one knows the fact that $J_0'(z)=-J_1(z)$
and your result follows:
$$
\frac12=\sum_{k=1}\frac1{\alpha_k J_1(\alpha_k)}
$$

Approach cleary works also for higher order Bessels...

Comment: Thanks a lot. I wonder if this can be applied to prove $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \exp(-\alpha_k^2)/(\alpha_k J_1(\alpha_k))=0$.